# how long must a sql server connection be idle before it is closed by the connection pool?

Tags: sql-server, connection-pooling

I have a client-server app that uses .NET SqlClient Data Provider to connect to sql server - pretty standard stuff. By default how long must connections be idle before the connection pooling manager will close the database connection and remove it from the pool? What setting if any controls this?

[This MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) only says

> The connection pooler removes a connection from the pool after it has been idle for a long time, or if the pooler detects that the connection with the server has been severed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few years ago the answer beneath was the situation, but now it's changed so you can refer to the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/ProviderBase/DbConnectionInternal.cs,525) and write up a summary :)

---

**Old answer**

[This excellent article](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716074725/http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/dotnet/archives/0112/smith/index.html) tells us what we need to know, using reflection to reveal the inner workings of connection pooling.

From how I understand it, 'closed' connections are cleaned up periodically on a semi-random interval. The cleanup process runs somewhere between every 2min and 3min 50s, but it needs to run twice before a 'closed' connection will be properly closed. Therefore after 7min 40s of being 'closed' the underlying sql connection should be properly closed, but it could be as short as 2min. At the time of writing the first connection pool created in a process would always have a timer interval of 3min 10s, so you'd normally see sql connections being closed somewhere between 3min 10s and 6min 20s after you call Close() on the ADO object.

Obviously this uses undocumented code so could change in future - or could even have changed since that article was written.

Comment: Be careful here. The [implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/ProviderBase/DbConnectionInternal.cs,525) has changed so the internals exposed by that article are not true anymore. The connection is really cleaned up.

Comment: So ... balance timeout is set to 0 meaning the connection is really closed instant? That is how I understand it. How does this help pooling underlying connection? Isn't this undermining the pooling?

Comment: Oooh. This is only if using load balancer and the connection isn't marked as being doomed.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28VS.80%29.aspx

The part

> "The following table lists the valid
>   names for connection pooling values
>   within the ConnectionString."

seems to be of your interest.

Comment: hmmm... the only setting that might be appropriate there is Load Balance Timeout, but that's a minimum not a max time so increasing it should make connections last longer. I want to know what "idle for a long time" means by default. If it's the connection pooling that decides a connection has been idle then it shouldn't be dependent on the SQL Server connection timeout. Also is there such a thing as the connection timeout of the SQL Server?

Comment: One can use Connection Lifetime to decide the max life of a connection (idle + used time).

Comment: Removed the part about connection timeout.
As per the available data, cant say when .NET will close the connection, but using Connection Lifetime & Load Balance timeout, I think you can somewhat control when the connection will break.
Also keep alive parameter of SQl Server will kill dead connections (not idle connections) incase of TCP/IP.

Comment: Connection Lifetime says it is only checked when a connection returns to a pool, and it's based on when the connection was created rather than how long since its last batch. Therefore I don't think it is useful in this context.

Comment: A connection is removed from a connection pool and the connection to the
database server is terminated when it sits idle (unused) for too long. The
length of time that a connection can sit idle in a connection pool before being
removed is determined by the Connection Lifetime connection string option.
A timestamp is attached to each connection that is released back to a
connection pool when the application calls Connection.Close(). The pool
manager then periodically checks the pools for connections that have
exceeded their Connection Lifetime.

Comment: Note, however, that the data provider will always retain the number of connections specified by the Min Pool Size connection option in a connection pool. So, setting the Min Pool Size connection option greater than 0 means that many connections in a pool will effectively ignore the Connection Lifetime connection option. ---- This is what I found in a PDF on Connection Pooling by DATADIRECT TECHNOLOGIES

Comment: According to the docs, ConnectionLifetime is the period since the connection was opened, not since it was last used. If so then it's not setting the idle timeout, and setting this will result in connections being unnecessarily closed when they're regularly being used. eg I want connections closed after 1 min of no use. If I use ConnectionTimeout then every db connection will be closed after 1 min. I only want ones that aren't being regularly used to be closed.