# SQL Server and VPN

Tags: sql-server

I have Point to point VPN Configured, and i am making use of SQL Server, i am able to connect the database while after few minutes it issues an error that connection has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may have issues with MTU or inspection if Cisco. Probably not the best place to ask so try serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Can this help you ?
[how long must a sql server connection be idle before it is closed by the connection pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136698/how-long-must-a-sql-server-connection-be-idle-before-it-is-closed-by-the-connecti)

Comment: for 1 to 2 minutes; the time taken by the user to make entry

Answer (score 0):

No problem here. If this is related to teh VPN (as opposed to things like general network problems) it must be very specific to your VPN setup, or some internal system.

I use Windwos VPN technology (client or office / office with RRAS) and as I said - no problems.