# Understanding ADO.NET 'Connection Lifetime'

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net, connection-pooling

I've come across a high-traffic app which occasionally hits various scaling timeout issues I'm trying to diagnose. The app has these settings in the SQL connection string:

```
Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=8;Connection Lifetime=30;
```

This of course means there are a minimum of 5 connections in the pool at all times, as confirmed by PerfMon.

But if I understand the Microsoft docs correctly, the **Connection Lifetime** setting is going to destroy any **closed connection** which has existed for more than 30 seconds:

> When a connection is returned to the pool, its creation time is
>   compared with the current time, and the connection is destroyed if
>   that time span (in seconds) exceeds the value specified by Connection
>   Lifetime.

As these 5 (or more) connections are constantly used, am I right in thinking that none of them will ever live beyond 30 seconds? Thus every half a minute or so, my application is going all the way back to SQL to handshake 5+ brand new connections?

PerfMon suggests the number of connections never drops below 5, so I've no evidence of the above taking place (unless it's visually instant). Have I misunderstood?

In addition, [this ancient article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/angelsb/2004/09/20/ado-net-the-misunderstood-connection-lifetime-managed-pooler-connection-string-keyword/) confirms the lifetime check is only performed on Close(), so this setting would have **no** benefit on addressing any connection leaks whatsoever?

Comment: The MinPoolSize keeps them alive; see the answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221687/why-do-we-need-to-set-min-pool-size-in-connectionstring

Comment: I agree it keeps a min number alive, but that question doesn't answer how MinPoolSize works in combination with ConnectionLifetime. According do the docs I quoted, those connections would still be killed after 30s, and re-created.

Comment: The way I understand is that these don't get destroyed; they stay alive for the duration of the application. An other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136698/how-long-must-a-sql-server-connection-be-idle-before-it-is-closed-by-the-connect) links to an (old) [really technical article](http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/dotnet/archives/0112/smith/index.html) mentioning: _closing connections until there are "Min Pool Size" connections left in the pool_.

Comment: Please update your question with the details of such an exception. If you have pooling issues, the most common one has to do with too few available ones: _"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."_